# Why did Yoda choose to live in Dagobah in exile?

Tags: star-wars, yoda, dagobah

Of all places, why Dagobah? What makes Dagobah so safe or comfortable for him?

Comment: Because it's a swamp, and frogs thrive in swamps!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the new [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything you Need to Know](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1465437851), Dagobah is ideal because it's

> Shrouded in clouds, thick with fog and far from the civilised galaxy,

making it the

> perfect refuge for a Jedi Master in hiding

It also mentions the planet's extremely high levels of life (allowing for a greater connection to the Force while he meditates on the downfall of the Jedi) and the Force cave which shrouds his light side Force from the Emperor.

Answer (score 8):

1. Dagobah was on the outer rim, far away from anywhere important or from anything of influence.
2. The tree/cave there had a strong dark side of the force presence which would have masked his ability with the force from Vader and the empire.